# Limit Question involving logarithmic taylor expansion

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

I need to evaluate the limit for part of my proof:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{\eta^{x}} \right)^n  $$

My attempt:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} F_{\eta_n}(x) &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{\eta^{x}} \right)^n \\&= \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{n\log{\left(1-\dfrac{1}{\eta^{x}} \right)}} \tag{*}
\end{align*}
Aside: Recall the Taylor expansion for $\log({1-y})$ is written as
\begin{align*}
\log({1-y}) &= -y-\dfrac{1}{2}y^2 - \dfrac{1}{3} y^3 -\dfrac{1}{4} y^4 - \cdots
\end{align*}
Now let $y =\dfrac{1}{\eta^{x}} $ and write (*) as:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} F_{\eta_n}(x) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \exp\left(-{\dfrac{n}{\eta^{x}}-\dfrac{n}{2}\left(\dfrac{1}{\eta^{x}}\right)^2 - \dfrac{n}{3} \left(\dfrac{1}{\eta^{x}}\right)^3 - \dfrac{n}{4} \left(\dfrac{1}{\eta^{x}}\right)^4 - \cdots}\right)
\end{align*}

When $x=0$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} F_{\eta_n}(x) = 0$

But I want to find the limit for all x. I am stuck with other values of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

The only $n$-dependence is in the power so let $t=1-\eta^{-x}$ and note that
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}t^n=\begin{cases}
0,&0\le t<1\\
1,& t=1\\
+\infty,& t>1\\
\text{doesn't exist otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$ 
Restricting $n$ to the natural numbers would further give $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}t^n=0\text{ if }|t|<1$$